# How to configure StructureMap in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, structuremap

I'm developing an application in WPF and I want to know how to begin configuring StructureMap. I'm coming from an MVC background where I would normally configure StructureMap in Global.asax.

The following article suggests that I put the configuration in the `main()` method

http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ConfiguringStructureMap.htm

but in WPF the `main()` method is located in `App.g.i.cs` and states

> This code was generated by a tool & Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if the code is regenerated.

In WPF there doesn't seem to be a suitable equivalent of Global.asax, so where should the configuration go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use App.xaml.cs for that.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        //Do your stuff here
    }
}
```